# Having a Flips side view and need to use UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, xcode4

I have a UIViewController class and it displays a plain text instructions, instead i need to use the UITableView to make it nicer and more neat so what is the easy way to do it?? The instructions are displayed as follows in the method updateView:

`textDisp.text = classInst.instructions`

instructions is from type NSString

Im not an expert in iPhone programing but trying to learn. I actually know how to use the TableView but not in this case where i have nothing related to UITableView but only a UIViewController

Comment: Do you want to add any effect in your table view or what exactly you want to do in your table view ,please elaborate your question

Comment: nothing actually no effects just a single view with some instructions

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to have single view on  the screen it could be either `UITableView` OR UIView (may be `UILabel`).

It could be possible by two way

First you could use the `removeFromSuperview` and `addSubview` method of `UIView` class.

Second Using the `hidden` property of `UIView`

Comment: yes you are right i need to have a single view and your solution seems to be easy but sorry im still confused about it!! do you mind giving me a short example please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take `UITableView` Control from Interface builder and put into your View. Take IBOutlet Tableview Var in your UIViewController and connect it. Place UItableViewDelegate Protocol name in your UIViewController .h file and implement Tableview delegate methods in your UIViewController .m file. Create TextView Object and add it in your UITableview cell.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your nib files as you wish and simply invoke the following code to invoke the flip view....

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
```